# File is bigger after copy

Tags: java

I am trying to upload a jar file using an API that takes an `InputStream` object as its source. When testing, I noticed that the uploaded file was bigger than the original and I couldn't open it after downloading.

I tried to just copy the resource to a file and open it, but it's the same behaviour:

```
InputStream original = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Example.jar");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
for (int read; (read = original.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
  baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
original.close();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("target/copy.jar");
fos.write(baos.toByteArray());
fos.close();
```

What is going wrong with the copying process?

**Update**: I tried to read the jar file using a `FileInputStream`, which made the copied jar identical. However, I still don't know why `getResourceAsStream("/Example.jar")` returns a bigger `InputStream`.

Comment: Using `getResourceAsStream` is usually not appropriate for reading jar files, because in most normal use cases, `getResourceAsStream` will only read content from within jar-files. In this case it probably works because you are executing this from your IDE or with loose `class`-files in a folder. That in itself however does not explain your problem.